# $.param($scope.formData) causes infinite loop

Tags: angularjs

This code creates an infinite loop:

```
$scope.signup = function() {
  $http({
    method: 'POST',
    data: $.param($scope.formData),
    url: '/api/signup',
    headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
  })
  .success(function(data) {
    console.log(data);
  })
}
```

HTML form:

```
<div data-ng-controller="signup">
  <form id="signup-form" name="singup-form" method="post" data-ng-submit="signup()" novalidate>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label>Email</label>
      <input class="form-control" type="email" name="email" placeholder="Your email" data-ng-model="formData.email">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group p-tb-20">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Signup</button>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

The problem arises when I call `$.param($scope.formData)`. When I inspect the `$scope.formData` object, I noticed that it contains circular references to itself and the models inside the `formData` object contain references to the objects inside the controller and again, itself. So, the function runs in an infinite loop.

All I'm trying to do is submit a form. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You should post data in request body directly like ` data:$scope.formData,`, why you need $.params there?

Comment: Because I want the data sent as a POST query and not inside the body of the request.

Comment: so then use `params` inspite of `data` option.. Technically it should passed from request body..

Comment: Correction: I want it sent as FormData and not as JSON-encoded body in the request (which happens if I just put $scope.formData)

Comment: try `$.param(angular.copy($scope.formData))` or use [$httpParamSerializerJQLike](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$httpParamSerializerJQLike)

Comment: @PankajParkar not the same thing. `params` is for GET query strings

Comment: @charlietfl, I get https://docs.angularjs.org/error/ng/cpws

Comment: must be doing something different than what I showed and trying to copy whole $scope

Answer (score 0):

First line in your view below should be controller name you are calling the method here directly.

```
<div data-ng-controller=**"signup()"**>
```

Comment: It was a typo, sorry!